# How to do a unit test to a java method?

Tags: java, testing, design-patterns

i have this method and i need do test unit with Junit, but i dont know how do it! someone can help me? Thanks.

```
public static boolean esTelefonoFijo(String telefonoFijo) {
    // pattern validate tlp
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^?[89]\\d{8}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(telefonoFijo);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: Welcome! What is the problem? How to run test? Which test case to write? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A unit test is usually located in a separate test class.
It should feed your method with an input and check if your expected result comes out.

A simple test for your method could be something like this:

```
@Test
public void testValidLandlineNumber() {

    // arrange
    String phonenumber = /*valid value string */

    // act
    boolean isValid = Phonenumber.esTelefonoFijo(phonenumber);

    // assert
    Assertions.assertTrue(isValid);
}
```

You can have similar test methods for other input values.

In case you don't yet have set-up JUnit in your IDE or build tool I'd recommend the following tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: thanks !  I have already solved it!